# Converting UN locations `coordinates` to lat and lng

Tags: python, coordinates

I have coordinates from the UNLOCATION dataset, that look like this: `4230N 00131E`.

According to their site, this is how it should be processed:
https://service.unece.org/trade/locode/Service/LocodeColumn.htm#Coordinates

> This column contains the geographical coordinates (latitude/longitude) of the location, if there is any.
>
> In order to avoid unnecessary use of non-standard characters and space, the following standard presentation is used:
>
> 0000lat 00000long
>
> (lat - Latitude: N or S ; long – Longitude: W or E, only one digit, capital letter)
>
> Where the last two rightmost digits refer to minutes and the first two or three digits refer to the degrees for latitude and longitude respectively. In addition, you must specify N or S for latitude and W or E for longitude, as appropriate.

Is there a formula for converting this structure into a valid lat & long or a package that does that in Python?
As it seems that converting `4230N 00131E` to `4230,00131` is not the correct solution.

Comment: From the documentation, it's clear that should be 42 degrees 30 minutes North, 1 degree 31 minutes East. A package like [latlon3](https://pypi.org/project/latlon3/) can easily convert that to any format for you.

Comment: Asking for libraries is explicitly disallowed on Stack Overflow, though you might like to explore our sibling site [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I wrote this code:

```
def convert_unlocation_to_lat_lng(unlocation_coordinates: str) -> Tuple[Optional[float], Optional[float]]:
    # Split the input string into latitude and longitude parts
    coordinates = unlocation_coordinates.split(" ")
    if not coordinates[0]:
        return None, None
    lat_str = coordinates[0]
    lng_str = coordinates[1]

    # Extract latitude and longitude values
    lat_numbers = lat_str[:-1]
    lat_deg = int(lat_numbers[:-2])
    lat_min = int(lat_numbers[-2:])
    lng_numbers = lng_str[:-1]
    lng_deg = int(lng_numbers[:3])
    lng_min = int(lng_numbers[3:])

    # Determine direction of latitude and longitude
    lat_dir = 'N' if lat_str.endswith('N') else 'S'
    lng_dir = 'E' if lng_str.endswith('E') else 'W'

    # Calculate latitude and longitude in decimal format
    latitude = lat_deg + lat_min / 60
    longitude = lng_deg + lng_min / 60

    # Adjust latitude and longitude based on direction
    if lat_dir == 'S':
        latitude *= -1
    if lng_dir == 'W':
        longitude *= -1

    return latitude, longitude
```